# xcode 6.0 brings a lot of errors and some strange questions about cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I build a project and it runs find in Xcode 5.0. But a few minutes ago ,I update the Xcode to the latest version. the project that can run fine in Xcode 5.0 cannot run in Xcode 6.0.

It has error:
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7fff56bf2fd8)
in SDWebImageDownloaderOperatin.m in SDWebImage.

```
- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}
```

Another question is about cocoa pods.
the latest version of sdwebimage in github is 3.6.
why i search in my computer used pod search SDWebImage, it tells me the latest version is 3.5.2?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're asking multiple questions they should be multiple questions. As for the CocoaPods question you need to update your local specs repo by running `pod repo update`